# Calling child relations from model in laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, eager-loading

I want to fetch the categories with products and images. I have following relation: 
**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{


    public function productCategory() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('ProductCategory');
    }

    public function addtionalImages() {

        return $this->hasMany('ProductImage');
    }
}
```

**Product Category Model**

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{

    public function product() {

       return $this->hasMany('Bazar\Models\Product', 'product_catid')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(10);
    }  
}
```

This is how i am using eager loading:

```
$categories = ProductCategory::select('product_categories.*')
              ->with(['product'])->Paginate(20);
```

This returns the category and products not the additionalImage, images are related to products not with the categories, I tried `->with(['product', 'addtionalImages'])` but no success, can anyone let me know what i missed? or how do i achieve?

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, and posting the answer so it helps to others.

```
$categories = ProductCategory::select('product_categories.*')
          ->with(['product', 'product.addtionalImages'])->Paginate(20);
```

With use of `product.addtionalImages` i can access the methods of related relation.

Answer (score 0):

Portfolio Model:

```
public function getCats(){
        return $this->hasMany(RelPortfolioCategory::class,'portfolioID','id');
    }
```

controller:

```
public function portfolioDetail($slug){
        $db = Portfolio::where('slug' , $slug)->with('getCats')->firstOrFail();
        $dbRelated = RelPortfolioCategory::whereIn('categoryID' , $db->getCats->pluck('categoryID'))->whereNot('portfolioID' , $db->id)
            ->with('getPortfolioDetail')->get();
        return view('portfolioDetail' , compact('db' , 'dbRelated'));
    }
```